# iPod Nano 6G stops playing when display turns off

Tags: headphones, ipod-nano

My iPod Nano 6G stops playing music when the display turns off either by time, or by pressing the "Sleep/Wake"-button.
This effect is fully reproducible but **only appears with certain headphones**, namely:

Sennheiser CX 1.00

JBL Synchros S100i

With several other headphones, the iPod keeps playing music when the display turns off.

Any advice how to get those headphones working with the iPod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the approaches to this error concern problems with the headphone jack and plug, so it was in this case.

Simply cleaning of the jack with compressed air didn't solve the problem. I had to **scratch the inside** (the part, the tip of the plug connects to) of the jack **carefully** with a paperclip and clean again with **compressed air** afterwards.

**Be aware that you may damage the iPod and void your warranty this way!**

Annotation:

- I don't know, if it was dirt or passivation that caused the erratic behaviour.
- The correlation with different ear buds is undeniable. This may be the cause of small differences within the specifications of the connectors, the headphones, or the MP3 device. Since I never had problems with other MP3 players, I tend to blame Apple.